# How does return-based analysis calculate expected return of a trading system?

Tags: analysis, expected-return

Suppose you have a trading system that is never flat, but either long or short the market. You have four years of performance. During that period, your system changed its position 10 times. So you have 10 trades from which to calculate expected return. Assume you always traded the same lot size. In a transaction-based analysis, you would compute your expected return based on the average win amount, average loss amount, percentage of trades that were winners and percentage of trades that were losers.

Assume the system had 5 winning trades and 5 losing trades. The average win was 100 dollars and the average loss was 50 dollars. You don't need the expected return formula to figure out if there is a positive expectation to this system.

```
Expected Return = (ave win * win percent) - (ave loss * lose percent)
```

Plug in our values we find:

```
Expected Return = (100 * .5) - (50 * .5) = 25 (dollars)
```

Alright, wonderful. Too bad we only have 10 trades though. Curiously, if you watch daily returns versus trade returns, you have 1008 observations (252*4). Does returns-based analysis calculate average positive daily returns, average negative daily returns and win/loss percentages in a manner similar to the transaction-based analysis? The `Expected Return` would not be a dollar value obviously, but a daily return value. So instead of 25 dollars, you'd get 0.0023423 for example. (NOTE:  0.0023423 is a completely made-up number in this example)

EDIT:

To the question of what frequency we calculate returns. Let's assume the trade system decides what position to be in tomorrow based on a signal given at the end of the current trading day. So our system calculates its signal daily, ergo we rationally only consider daily returns.

EDIT #2: Our system generates a signal every day, but in our example that signal has only changed 10 times during the course of 4 years. The signal can be either a 1 (long) or -1 (short). If we were previously short (-1) and the signal triggered a change to long (1), we would switch our short position to a long position. If the next day the signal triggered long, we would maintain our current position.

Comment: If your position changed only 10 times in 4 years, I would be a bit worried about data mining

Comment: @fRed does viewing the exact same system over the same time frame as daily returns (and increasing your observations 100 fold) address those data mining worries (which I share)?

Comment: With regard to concerns over data mining, it would be trivially simple to apply the tests outlined in Aronson's book, "Evidence Based Technical Analysis," to the above posited system to determine the extent to which data mining bias has an influence on the system's returns.

Comment: I don't have access to the book, what is this test?

Comment: @ MilkTrader. To answer specifically your question, I disagree. What counts is the number of times your indicator changes. Consider your strategy with milliseconds if you want, you won't change the fact that you have 10 trading decisions in 4 years

Comment: @RockScience I added an edit to the question to clarify that our example system generates signals daily.

Comment: @MikTrader - I don't understand your edit.  If you are getting a new signal every day, you have a daily trading system and you would calculate your ER based on that.  If your signal lasts more than a day, you can't calculate an ER daily since the daily returns are due to other factors as time passes. For example if you are in a trade for a year, the chances are very slim that the return on your last day is due to your original trading signal

Comment: @RockScience. The tests are a Monte Carlo permutation test and a bootstrap test on detrended returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add returns. You must multiply them.
In your example above where daily returns are 25%, 25%, and -40%

To compute expected return from a return series, simply use this formula:
return =  product( 1+return);

in the case of you example this yields:
 return = (1.25 * 1.25 * .6) = .9375

To get the expected daily return use the geometric mean:
expected return = (1.25 * 1.25 * .6)^(1/3)  -1 = -2.13%

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean

Comment: and don't forget the most important metric... max drawdown.

Comment: What is the equation for taking daily returns and calculating expected return?

Comment: @Milktrader: Technically it's the average of the daily returns.  That is the expectation on any given day.  However, normally this is not sufficient information.  To make it useful one needs to look at winning trades vs losing trades and generate a histogram and then normalize(z-score) so that you end up with a confidence interval that allows you to say X% of the time the daily return will be within Z standard deviations of the expected daily return.  Then you can choose how to size/risk decision upcoming trades.

Comment: I get the winning trades vs losing trades metric, but that's the transaction-based analysis. The original question is "Does returns-based analysis calculate average positive daily returns, average negative daily returns and win/loss percentages in a manner similar to the transaction-based analysis?" This question is specific to returns-based analysis.

Comment: @Milktrader  Ahh, I see what you're saying, (trade vs return).  This is why I mentioned the part about, "any level of granularity that you have data"  So if daily returns is what you have, you still compute the average daily return, then look at min daily return, max daily return, and build a histogram, normalize, and go from there...   This is a long way to say, YES...  return based analysis uses the same approach as transaction based.

Comment: @glyphard but that approach yields nonsense results, as shown in my answer. If it can't get it right with three trades, who knows what accumulated error you'll get after a few hundred trades.

Comment: @MilkTrader:  don't use the arithmetic mean to calculate the expectation, use the geometric mean.  this shows you the negative expectation in the case of your example, and the rest of the analysis still works.  Geometric mean requires that all of your data samples are on evenly spaced data(like daily in your example).  Also geometric mean is guaranteed to be _always_ less than or equal to the arithmetic mean.  (in your example the geometric mean is 93.75%, clearly indicating that you should use this trading system)

Comment: @glyphard in my game function, you start with 100 and always end up with only 93.75 at the end of the game. It's not a mean calculation (geometric or arithmetic) but rather an illustration of a losing game. I got one possible way to determine expected return from actual returns here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_return.

Comment: instead of "clearly indicating that you should use this trading system"  I mean clearly you should NOT use this system.  Just compounding the returns returns (1.25*1.25*.6 - 1)  gives u -6.25  (you can't add %'s together, you have to multiply them  then it works.)   (geometric return does this)

Comment: @glyphard, please re-write your answer. Delete the first five paragraphs and express an equation that reflects what I think you are getting at in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Returns-based analysis cannot calculate the expected return of a trading system. It yields nonsensical results and is not suited to this particular calculation.

Consider a game where every time you play, you win 25% twice and lose 40% once. There are basically three permutations of this game. Represented in R vectors:

```
first  <- c(.25, .25, -.4)
second <- c(-.4, .25, .25)
third  <- c(.25, -.4, .25)
```

Here is a simple function that takes each sequence individually and returns what's left from your stack of 100 chips.

```
game <- function(x){

start <- 100

for(i in 1:NROW(x))

start <- start + start*x[i]

return(start)   
}
```

Try it yourself and you will see that each time, the result is `93.75`. You lose every time. If you calculate the expected return in the canonical manner, you get the following:

```
Expected Return = (.25 * .33) + (.25 * .33) + (-.40 * .33) = 0.033
```

This is a positive value for a game in which you cannot win. If you sum returns, you get the following:

```
Sum Returns = .25 + .25 + (-.40) = .10
```

Again, a positive value for a game in which you always lose.

If you analyze your expected return using transaction-based analysis as given in the original question, you get the same result each time. The answer comes to `-2.0625`. A negative expectation that will keep you clear from playing this game.

UPDATE: this answer was based on the false assumption that you can add simple returns, and of course you can only add log returns.

```
Simple Returns = 1.25 * 1.25 * .6 = .9375

Log Returns = log(1.25) + log(1.25) + log(.6) =  -0.06453852
antilog of sum = exp( -0.06453852) = .9375
```